# How to share a menu across more website

Tags: 7, routes, feeds

I've got a main website where it's possible to create and change menu items and I need to share this menu with other websites and programmatically(once per week or once per day) the other websites will import and override the menu.

This is very useful when a company has got more websites and wants to use the same footer menu for all its websites.

Do I need to use just Feeds and Rules to achieve it?
Is it possible to achieve it without adding the main website db menu in settings.php in all the other websites?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea of using a feed is an attractive one. I don't think there's any way to push a menu definition out as a feed using existing modules, though.

I'd write a very simple module to provide a single callback that would fetch the menu definition and theme it as xml or json (easier). That could then be fetched at intervals by your other sites.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to create a menu view with json format?

Comment: Yes, something like print `json_encode(menu_tree('my_menu'))` would be the simplest code to do it.

Comment: It looks interesting. I will test it in these days. Thanks Alfred.